# Frama-C generates confusing assertions about pointer comparison

Tags: frama-c

I'm getting assertions that don't make sense to me.

Code:

```c
struct s {
    int pred;
};

/*@ assigns \result \from \nothing;
    ensures \valid(\result);
*/
struct s *get(void);

int main(void)
{
    return !get()->pred;
}
```

Frama-C output:

```
$ frama-c -val frama-ptr.c
[...]
frama-ptr.c:12:[kernel] warning: pointer comparison.
                  assert \pointer_comparable((void *)0, (void *)tmp->pred);
                  (tmp from get())
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in Frama-C?

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the issue in more detail

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a bug, although this behavior is not really satisfactory either. I recommend that you observe the analysis in the GUI (`frama-c-gui -val frama-ptr.c`), in particular the value of `tmp->pred` at line 12 in the *Values* tab.

```
Value before:
 ∈
{{ garbled mix of &{alloced_return_get}
 (origin: Library function {c/ptrcmp.c:12}) }}
```

This is a very imprecise value, that has been generated because the return value of function `get` is a pointer. The Eva plugin generates a dummy variable (`alloced_return_get`), and fills it with dummy contents (`garbled mix of &{alloced_return_get}`). Even though the field `pred` is an integer, the analyzer assumes that (imprecise) pointers can also be present. This is why an alarm for pointer comparison is emitted.

There are at least two ways to avoid this:

- use option `-val-warn-undefined-pointer-comparison pointer`, so that pointer comparison alarms are emitted only on comparisons involving lvalues with pointer type. The contents of the field `pred` will remain imprecise, though.
- add a proper body to function `get`, possibly written using `malloc`, so that the field `pred` receives a more accurate value.

On a more general note, the Eva/Value plugin requires precise specifications for functions without a body; see section 7.2 of the manual. For functions that return pointers, you won't be able to write satisfactory specifications: you need to write `allocates` clauses, and those are currently not handled by Eva/Value. Thus, I suggest that you write a body for `get`.